# Javascript parameter ignoring

Tags: javascript

The linting for the following would complain that 'unused' is defined but never used.

```
function foobar( unused, used ) { return used }
```

In Ruby, you can do

```
def foobar( _unused, used)
  used
end
```

using '_' to signify that 'unused' is not being used and is merely required as a parameter in the method signature. Is it possible to do this in javascript?

Comment: No, its not possible.

Comment: what linter are you using? eslint seems to allow it based on the ESLint Demo repl

Comment: eslint, though its a more general question ^'_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ESLint, you can use `//eslint-disable-next-line` above the function definition to avoid this linting error.